# If statements not behaving the way they should

Tags: javascript, if-statement, boolean, alert

I wrote this function, in javascript, that should add and remove objects from an array and alert that it is doing it.

```
function modifyWatchlist(id, boolean, array)  {
    const isAdding = boolean
    const targetMovie = array.filter(movie => movie.imdbID === id)
    const isRepeated = watchlist.find(movie => movie.imdbID === id)
    
    if (isAdding && isRepeated != undefined) {
        alert('Film already in your watchlist')
    } 
    else if (isAdding && isRepeated === undefined) {
        // watchlist.push(targetMovie[0])
        // localStorage.setItem('watchlist', JSON.stringify(watchlist))
        alert('Film added to your watchlist')
    }
    else if (!isAdding) {
        // const newWatchlist = watchlist.filter(movie => movie.imdbID !== id)
        // localStorage.setItem('watchlist', JSON.stringify(newWatchlist))
        alert('Film removed from your watchlist')
    }   
}
```

When running the code above, the `alert('Film already in your watchlist')` statement runs even when `isAdding === false`. I do not understand the logic behind that and could not find a way to fix it. The `alert('Film removed from your watchlist')` statement still works as expected but the `alert('Film already in your watchlist')` always runs first.

That is one way the function is called:

```
document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const id = e.target.dataset.id
    if (id) {
        modifyWatchlist(id, true, currentMovies)
    }
    else if (e.target.id === 'search-btn') {
        e.preventDefault()
        getMoviesArray()
    }
})
```

That is an other way this function is called

```
document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
                const id = e.target.dataset.id
                if (e.target.dataset.id) {
                    modifyWatchlist(id, false, watchlist)
                    initWatchlist()
                }
            })
```

Comment: [guard clauses](https://maximegel.medium.com/what-are-guard-clauses-and-how-to-use-them-350c8f1b6fd2#:~:text=A%20guard%20clause%20is%20a,deeper%20and%20less%20meaningful%20error.) are your friend here

Comment: @MikeWarren I wouldn't say 3 if conditions is messy code at all.

Comment: I had less if conditions but I tried to separete them and be more specific in each of them to see if it would fix it.

Comment: When `isAdding` is `false`, is it literally `false` or is it the string `"false"`?

Comment: What is `watchlist` ? ( in `const isRepeated = watchlist.find(movie => movie.imdbID === id)` ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get the best answers to your question we like to see that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first using a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Here's a [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) you might find useful...

Comment: @Pointy isAdding is the boolean false.  It is defined when calling the function: modifyWatchlist(id, false, array) or modifyWatchlist(id, true, array). Watchlist is an array of objects that is saves data of movies to be added to a watchlist and added to the local storage

Comment: "*When running the code above*" - please show us how exactly you are calling the function. You can [edit] your question to include a [mcve]

Comment: I'm betting on a type error, but since nothing can be known with this meager code sampling, I wonder why you want it to be a logic error with `if`s ?.

Answer (score 1):

The problem had nothing to do with the if statements, it was due to how I organized the my code between .js files and different .HTML files.

Thanks to everybody that tried to help, I'll be deleting this question soon.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using your instinct, why not try console.log your isRepeated variable before entering if else statement? Traditional way works most of the time and worth the hassle .

For example

```
console.log("test1: " + isRepeated != undefined)
console.log("test2: " + isRepeated === undefined)
console.log("test3: " + isAdding)
```

Comment: Thank you! Tried it, the results where as expected, the 'isRepeated' variable is different than undefined when the target is  a 'repeated' object (an object that is equal to an other that is stored in the watchlist array) and equal to undefined when the target object is found in the watchlist array

Answer (score 0):

Can you show me how you are calling this function? Also, it is a great idea to use console.log for debugging purposes. You can add logs before the if checks to confirm the values. I have tested your code on a separate editor and it seems 'Film already in your watchlist' only displaying when isAdding is true.

Here is how I used your function.

```
watchlist = [{"imdbID": 1}]
array = [{"imdbID": 1}]
modifyWatchlist(1, false, array)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The function takes three parameters: modifyWatchlist(id, boolean, array).
'id' is a unique id that differs one object from another;
'boolean' is true when adding a movie to the watchlist and 'false' when removing it;
'array' is the array that will be filtered to find the full object that has the 'id'.

Comment: Added information to my question above. Hope it's more clear now.

Comment: Thank you for adding the details.

Can you try your function by using hardcoded values just as I did to confirm if your function is working as expected? It might be possible that the values you are passing from the events are not being sent as you are expecting.

Comment: When using hardcoded values the function performed as expected. But when using the actual movie arrays and logging '(isRepeated !== undefined)', it logged 'true' to objects that were already stored, which is fine, but logged it two times. The thing that I cant understand is why, when using the actual arrays, the 'if(isAdding)' statement is completly ignored.